# How can I dim the screen after inactivity even when plugged into power?

Tags: 16.04, screen, brightness

I am creating a kiosk using Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. To decrease the amount of screen burn in/persistence, I would like the screen to dim after inactivity. However, the only settings I can find to do this are under `Brightness & Lock > Dim screen to save power` and work only when the system is on battery power. This PC is running on AC power all the time. Thus the screen never dims.

I do not want to use a screensaver, as users of this kiosk app will be monitoring on-screen contents from time to time just by glancing at it, and shouldn't have to interact just to view the status.

Basically I want precisely what "Dim screen to save power" offers, but I want it when plugged in, too. I can only seem to find the inverse question in ask ubuntu.

Comment: did you check Power Management settings?

Comment: Are you using an old CRT monitor? If not, you don't need to worry about "burn ins".

Comment: I did check power management settings, but all I see is controls for when to suspend or power off. Nothing about dim.

Comment: @MichaelBay unfortunately we have seen image persistence on our LCD monitors after about a year.